# [C++, windows form]How do I make the main thread wait for the called thread to finish?

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I created 2 buttons, one for start a new thread, the other to end it. The actual calculation inside the new thread involved new[] and delete[] so I don't abort the thread directly, but using a flag to end it. It may take some time to end the delete[] and result-saving, so I want the main thread to wait for the new thread to end. But however I tried, I find the new thread doesn't run(though its ThreadState is running) until the command lines for the stop-button are conducted. System::Threading::Thread works quite different from thread to me. Is it how it should be?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

ref class Form1 : System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
//define a thread name and a flag to terminate the thread
System::Threading::Thread^ th1;
static bool ITP1=0;

Form1(void)
{InitializeComponent();}

System::Windows::Forms::Button^ ButtonStart;
System::Windows::Forms::Button^ ButtonStop;
System::Windows::Forms::Label^ Label1;

void InitializeComponent(void)
{
    this->SuspendLayout();

    this->ButtonStart = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button();
    this->ButtonStart->Location = System::Drawing::Point(20, 20);
    this->ButtonStart->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::ButtonStart_Click);
    this->Controls->Add(this->ButtonStart);

    this->ButtonStop = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button();
    this->ButtonStop->Location = System::Drawing::Point(120, 20);
    this->ButtonStop->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::ButtonStop_Click);
    this->Controls->Add(this->ButtonStop);

    this->Label1 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label();
    this->Label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(20, 80);
    this->Controls->Add(this->Label1);

    this->ResumeLayout(false);
    }

void ThreadStart()
{
    for (int idx=0;idx<999999999;++idx)
    {
        if (ITP1) break;
    }
    this->Label1->Text = "finished";
    ITP1=0;
}

System::Void ButtonStart_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    th1 = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this,&Form1::ThreadStart));
    th1->Start();
    this->Label1->Text = "running";
}

System::Void ButtonStop_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    if (th1->ThreadState==System::Threading::ThreadState::Running)
    {
        //use the flag to stop the thread
        ITP1=1;
        //the wait method using while+sleep doesn't work
        while (th1->ThreadState==System::Threading::ThreadState::Running)   System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(1000);
        //replacing the wait method above with "th1->Join()" doesn't work either
    }
}
};

int main()
{
Form1^ A1 = gcnew Form1();
A1->ShowDialog();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you determine it doesn’t run? Did you use a debugger to see what’s happening?

Comment: Yes. I add a break under System::Void ButtonStop_Click. th1->ThreadState is always Running though no actions are performed. So the while loop is dead.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint inside the thread? That’s the only way to know if it’s running since it doesn’t do anything.

Comment: Debug doesn't work correctly with threading for my VC++ express. The command lines under the button is how far it can go. But I printed the ThreadState to the label. So without debug I also know if it's running or stopped.

Comment: "`Join` me and together we shall rule the universe." -Darth Threader

Comment: You say "Visual C++ Express". Which version are you using? Please note that versions of Visual Studio that had "Express" editions are outdated for nearly a decade. I strongly suggest using Visual Studio Community 2017. Also I doubt that you are using the original "Managed-C++" but rather "C++/CLI" which was not really intended to write GUI-code but as interop language (glue) between managed and unmanaged code.

Comment: Right. My VC++2005 Express classified this template as CLR/Windows Forms Application, and the example used managed C++. I don't really know the difference. I have also installed 2010 Express and haven't found any difference except their projects are not compatible. I suppose the result of the same command shouldn't differ a lot in newer compiler versions, right?

Comment: Sometimes it can differ greatly. C++ changed a lot in the 2011 Standard revision and some rules changed significantly. Some bad code, like `char * bad = "bad";` is now expressly forbidden because `"bad"` could be in read-only storage and writing to it has always been bad, but ignored for legacy support. By forcing `const char * good = "good";`, countless mistakes are likely being eradicated daily. The behaviour of the `auto` keyword is utterly different.

Comment: I add a break inside ThreadStart, and start debug. It breaks there after th1->start(). After I click the other button to stop the thread, the break doesn't work. The created thread is paused and the main thread waits for it forever. That's enough to prove the created thread is not running(but its state is "Running").

Answer (score 1):

You have to `join()` the called thread in the main thread. Then the main thread will wait until the called thread is finished.

See the documentation for [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) to know how it is to be called.

Comment: I've read this documentation before I ask the question here. In fact, I used Join() in the main thread(the form is called by the main function) while the documentation seems to use it in the new threads.

Comment: All my scripts are above. You can see I only created one thread, and used ButtonStop_Click to stop it. So ButtonStop_Click can only be called from the main thread.

Comment: It looks as if you are using `th1->Join()` in the created thread. The join should be called in the main thread, soon after starting the created thread.

Comment: No. th1->Join() is called inside the form class, which is in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the cause. It's just the "this->" pointer in the new thread. Removing it makes everything OK.
I suppose it's because the Form allows operation on only one element at the same time. I ask the button-click to wait for the new thread, and the new thread tries to edit the other form element. They wait for each other to end and cause a dead loop.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. I have to find other solutions. I need the created thread to return the result to UI and update the progress bar so I cannot simply remove the "this" pointer.